# How to send an arrayList from Apex to Javascript and then to HTML?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html, javascript-controller

I'm new in JS and can't understand, what is wrong here (this is my test value, but then I want to send an arraylist's elements):
Apex:

```
public String test{get;set;}
public String myApexMethod(){
    test = 'Hello!';
    return test;
}
```

JS and HTML:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!myApexMethod}" name="getResult" 

rerender="script_block"/>
<apex:outPutPanel layout="block" id="script_block">
 <script>
   var res = "{!test}";
   window.onload=func
    function func()
    {
        document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=res
    }
 </script>
</apex:outPutPanel>

<div id="d"></div>
```

And I get nothing on my VF page (when the method is void - I get nothing too). How can I fix it?

Comment: The code here does not call `getResult()`. Where do you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, because onload only happens when the page loads, and we're way beyond that stage now. Instead, call the method in oncomplete, and that should work:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!myApexMethod}" 
                     name="getResult"
                     oncomplete="func()" 
                     rerender="script_block"/>
```

This change presumes you have some way of calling getResult elsewhere in the page. The return type of your Apex code should indeed be null. As an action method, you only use a return type if you intend to redirect to a new page.